# Decode HTTP packet content in python as seen in wireshark

Tags: python, http, tcp, sniffing

Ok, so bascially what I want to do is intercept some packets that I know contains some JSON data. But HTTP packets aren't human-readable, so that's my problem, I need to make the entire packet (not just the header, which is already plain text), human-readable. I have no experience with networking at all.

```
import pcap
from impacket import ImpactDecoder, ImpactPacket

def print_packet(pktlen, data, timestamp):
    if not data:
        return

    decoder = ImpactDecoder.EthDecoder()
    ether = decoder.decode(data)
    iphdr = ether.child()
    tcphdr = iphdr.child()

    if iphdr.get_ip_src() == '*******':
        print tcphdr

p = pcap.pcapObject()
dev = 'wlan0'
p.open_live(dev, 1600, 0, 100)

try:
    p.setfilter('tcp', 0, 0)
    while 1:
        p.loop(1, print_packet)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'shutting down'
```

I've found tools like libpcap-python, scapy, Impacket pcapy and so on. They all seem good, but I can't figure out how to decode the packets properly with them.

Wireshark has this thing called "Line-based text data: text/html" which basically displays the information I'm after, so I thought it would be trivial to get the same info with python, it turns out it was not.

Comment: Why aren't the contents human readable?  I thought JSON was text?

Comment: JSON is, it's just that sniffed HTTP packets aren't.

Comment: HTTP is plain text too. Maybe you're talking about compressed or encrypted HTTP streams.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel, well maybe I'm just sniffing it wrong? This is what I'm getting with wireshark: {"EVENTS":[{"USERID":"688933540","TIME":1298126202,"TYPE":"MESSAGE","TOCHAN":1176,"TOUSER":"","MESSAGE":"surahammar","USER_NAME":"Gr8one"}],"LASTID":"20102651"}

Comment: @Arvin, suggest you edit your original post, add the sniffed data there, and delete your comment (that's the way to do it on SO when you want to add information).

Comment: @Arvin, and BTW, what what you posted as the captured data IS JSON.  That's what JSON looks like.  Not sure why you think it's not "human-readable".

Answer (score 2):

Both HTTP and JSON are human readable. On Wireshark, select a packet that relates to your HTTP transaction and right-click, select Follow TCP Stream, which should display the transaction in a Human readable form.